# Tor Browser, Signature verification Failed. Cant check signature: No public key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, signature, verification, tor

I'm trying to install tor manually on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver using this guide [how-to-install-tor-browser-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tor-browser-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) 
when I try to verify my signature key it says, No public Key, Checkout the error below

```
gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-8.0.6_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux64-8.0.6_en-US.tar.xz
gpg: Signature made و 18:27:41 PKT ت 12 فروری 2019
gpg:                using RSA key EB774491D9FF06E2
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: Removed the picture, going to post in TOR community too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Tor Project's [signing keys](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en) page for more info.

If you followed that tutorial exactly, then you imported a single developer's signing key, but this is not the key used to sign the browser releases.

The output you supplied shows that the actual signing key is `EB774491D9FF06E2`, which shows up on the Tor PGP keys page.

To properly verify, import the correct signing key:

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys EB774491D9FF06E2
```

Then you should be able to verify the package's signature using `--verify`.